# Two fragment can't weight in the Linear layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

i try to display a two-pane UI design. I try to add two fragments in a linear layout with a weight. However, the linear layout seems to ignore the weight. How do i correct it?? Thanks

[Link:] http://dl.dropbox.com/u/78582670/twopanes.png

my layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<fragment
    class="com.usci.view.fragment.CatalogFragment"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_catalog"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.2">
</fragment>

<fragment
    class="com.usci.education.TestFragment1"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_test"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.8">
</fragment>

</LinearLayout>
```

Solution:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<fragment
    class="com.usci.view.fragment.CatalogFragment"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_catalog"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="8">
</fragment>

<fragment
    class="com.usci.education.TestFragment1"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_test"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2">
</fragment>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try giving weight as 2 & 8 respectively

Comment: try it. But, not i want. In fact, i want really to weight the first fragment to 8.

Comment: then interchange it , try and error dude.

Comment: i solve it. But, i don't know why the setting is strange. @@"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

always , when you use weights , set the width/height (of the children) to 0px ,and prefer integers for the weights .

so , the solution is :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<fragment
    class="com.usci.view.fragment.CatalogFragment"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_catalog"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2">
</fragment>

<fragment
    class="com.usci.education.TestFragment1"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_test"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="8">
</fragment>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Not always - I believe you could perfectly assign a `layout_width` of 200dp and set `layout_weight` to distribute remaining space on top of the 200dp.

Comment: @sstn Lint warns about such a thing that it's not needed and causes extra calculations for nothing. however, maybe i didn't understand you or you didn't understand my answer.

Comment: I just referred to your statement "always set width/height to 0 when using weights", which I consider simply wrong or too simplified. I gave a valid case of combining width and weight - which is very different from the case where you just set width to 0.

Comment: Then I don't understand. I think it's hard to explain this, but could you please try again? maybe post some code (you can use pasteBin)?

Answer (score 0):

With me is working by putting 20,80 .. try also **0.8,0.2**:

```
<fragment
class="com.usci.view.fragment.CatalogFragment"
android:id="@+id/fragment_catalog"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="0.8">
</fragment>

<fragment
    class="com.usci.education.TestFragment1"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_test"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.2">
</fragment>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set android:layout_width and android:layout_height value match_parent, then for example set android:layout_weight (1 fragment and 2 fragment) value 1

Comment: Two fragment divide into two same size

Comment: Yes. You need change fragments weight. For example for 1st fragment set weight 1 and for second fragment set weight 8, play with weight :)